# inconsistent training/validation loss when using Caffe library to resume training with snapshots

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

As we know, Caffe supports resuming training when the snapshot is given. An explanation of Caffe's training continuation scheme can be found [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Training-and-Resuming). However, I found the training loss and validation loss is inconsistent. I gives the following example to illustrate my point. Suppose, I am training a neural network with maximum iteration 1000, and every 100 training iteration it will keep a snapshot. This is done using the following command:

```
caffe train -solver solver.prototxt
```

where the batch size is selected to be 64, and in solver.prototxt we have:

```
  test_iter: 4
  max_iter: 1000
  snapshot: 100
  display: 100
  test_interval: 100
```

We select `test_iter=4` carefully so that it will perform testing on nearly all the validation dataset (there are 284 validation samples, a little larger than 4*64).

This will gives us a list of .caffemodel and .solverstate files. For example, we may have solver_iter_300.solverstate and solver_iter_300.caffemodel. When generating these two files, we can also see the training loss (13.7466) and validation loss (2.9385).

Now, if we use the snapshot solver_iter_300.solverstate to continue training:

```
 caffe train -solver solver.prototxt -snapshot    solver_iter_300.solverstate
```

We can see the training loss and validation loss are 12.6 and 2.99 respectively. They are different from before. Any ideas? Thanks.